# Bypassing "final local variable defined in an enclosing type"

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing a program and i'm getting this "The final local variable asd cannot be assigned, since it's defined in an enclosing type".

I will provide with an example which is not from my code but this produces the error aswell. I have an arraylist which i would like to use later (if i define it inside the button i can't use it later on), outside of a button, but pressing the button should give values to this arraylist. In this example it will "create a new ArrayList" which will cause the same problem.

```
        Button btn = new Button("ASD");
        final ArrayList asd = new ArrayList();
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
                asd = new ArrayList(); //here's the error..
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear the ArrayList and then add the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Button btn = new Button("ASD");
final ArrayList[] asd = new ArrayList[1];
asd[0] = new ArrayList();
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
        asd[0] = new ArrayList();
    }
});
```

This is a useful page: [link](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/08/19/mutable-variable-capture-in-anonymous-java-classes/)

Comment: It removes the error, although when i run the program it will give an index 0 size 0 error.